# Send array to subshell function with pipe?

Tags: bash

I really need to get an array to a subshell so the processes can run together in one script. I know I cannot export an array but is it possible to send it through a pipe to a subshell, and how would I do that? Let's say I have a function `running()`; what would the content need to be so I could update the array in it when it changes in the main program. I would not like to store the array in files since that would be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a function using `myfunction() ( ... )` instead of `myfunction() { ... }` (so it will run in a subshell) and pass in your array as function arguments.

```
myfunc() (
  for f in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done
)

myfunc these arguments "are passed" 'to myfunc'

myarray=( "These values" "are set as" part 'of an array' )

myfunc "${myarray[@]}"
```

Output looks like:

```
these
arguments
are passed
to myfunc
These values
are set as
part
of an array
```

---

Note: That's just an example function, but actually here is a simpler version that does the same thing:

```
myfunc_simpler() (
  printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```